# Proving continuity from local uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> Prove that if $(f_n (x))$ converges locally uniformally to $f$ and all $f_n$ are continuous, then $f$ is continuous.

I know how to prove that uniform convergence implies continuity of $f$, but not local uniform convergence, unless the only difference is, in proving continuity of $f$ at $x$, we restrict ourselves to a neighborhood at which the convergence is uniform and then use the same argument.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Continuity is a local property. So, if $x_0$ belongs to the domain $D$ of your functions, take a neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ in $D$ such that $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $V$. The, since uniform convergence preserves continuity, $f|_V$ is continuous. But $V$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$. So, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.